# Dell XPS13 - Wiresless network drops out even when not suspended and no traffic

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend, dell

The wifi on my new Dell XPS (2017 model) is dropping out intermittently with no particular pattern. Each time that it drops out I'm able to resume the connection by running:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Sometimes the connection will last for an hour without issue, but typically it will only last for 20-30 minutes before dropping out.

I've done some research and found that this often happens when you have suspended and tried to resume their laptops however in my case it seems to happen at any time and I suspect it's due to the network card receiving a poor network signal, losing connection, and then not resuming at any point (which isn't a problem for any other device in the same location).

My lsb release is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

And the output of lshw -class network is:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:d7:58:67
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.10.0-22-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=10.0.0.55 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:282 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
```

I don't believe it to be related but I'm also running i3wm-gaps as my window manager which is the only major change I've made from a clean install. All packages are up to date, and I've set Ubuntu to update vendor drivers with update/upgrade. I'm a bit sure what else to try - and the laptop is unusable with this issue as I depend on a stable VPN connection for my work. What else can I try?